# Taking long time to generate excel file using POI

Tags: java, excel

In my project i want to generate a Excel file with 85 columns and rows will increase day by day.

Right now i have around 6K records. while generating file its always giving me Java Heap space exception.

My heap space setting is

> -Xmx2048M
>
> -Xmx6144M

My code is

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FIELD OPERATIONS TRACKER");

for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
 HSSFRow rowHeader = sheet.createRow(i);

 HSSFCell cell = rowHeader.createCell(0);
 cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getName());

 cell = rowHeader.createCell(1);
 cell.setCellValue(list.get(i).getSeason());

//like this  I have 85 columns here
}
```

Please help me to improve performnce

Comment: You are generating a old .xls file and not a .xlsx file ? Is there a good reason for this ?
If you want to create a xlsx file you can use a SXSSFWorkbook instead of a HSSFWorkbook

Comment: @rjdkolb i will try with .xlsx

Comment: XSSFWorkbook is the general xlsx writer . SXSSFWorkbook is the better one for very large docs. I generate 10-20 meg documents with low amounts of ram.

Comment: @rjdkolb i got same problem with SXSSFWorkbook. In for loop only i am getting heap space exception

Comment: with 3.13 changed your code on my side to have a 85 loop count to create 85 columns and a list size of 6000. It created a xlsx file of 1.2 meg in about 2 seconds.

Comment: i am using 3.9 vesrion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97273/discussion-between-rjdkolb-and-suman-tipparapu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create .xlsx file and not .xls files, simply swap out your new HSSFWorkbook() with a new SXSSFWorkbook()

```
Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
```

The guys at Apache POI did a good job of keeping things about the same. Just use the interfaces and not specific classes like HSSFCell and HSSFRow.

You will need two dependencies in your project :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Latest, try using 3.13

Comment: sorry this approach also giving me same problem.Actually i have to write 85 cell in single row,is that the problem?

Comment: This is the code I am running : https://gist.github.com/rjdkolb/56c3c0cf4929b0d2bcf6

Answer (score 0):

Constant.MAX_ROW_IN_MEMORY=1000; // A constant set to 1000

SXSSFWorkbook workBook = new SXSSFWorkbook(Constant.MAX_ROW_IN_MEMORY);
workBook.setCompressTempFiles(true);

Try creating the excel file with the one argument constructor.. and setCompressTempFiles to true.. Successfully wrote 2 Lakh records in single excel with less than 1 GB of memory.